# Routing ASP.NET Core 5 - default value of id always returns 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I have a project in ASP.NET Core 5, what I need is quite simple. I want to indicate in the `id` value a default int value in routing. However, when I trace the controller, it always returns the id as `0` or `null`.

```cs
public IActionResult Seccion(int id)
{
   
    return View();
}
```

this is my Start.up file

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=podcast}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "historias",
                        pattern: "seccion/{id=300}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Podcast", action = "Seccion" });

        });
```

As you can see, I expect when the `https://localhost:xxx/podcast/seccion/historias` is entered the `Seccion()` action method is called with `id` set to `300` by default. But the `id` always arrives `0`.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem caused by wrong routes registration order ([conventional routing is order-dependent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-up-conventional-route)).
It is important that you add ***"historias"*** route before the Default one.  Routes are processed in the order they are listed. So, define routes in the following order:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {      
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "historias",
                        pattern: "{controller}/seccion/historias/{id=300}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Podcast", action = "Seccion" });

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        pattern: "{controller=podcast}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

And the ***"historias"*** route template does not include the controller name. Therefore it is necessary to use the following URL: `https://localhost:port/seccion` or `https://localhost:port/seccion/[some_number_here]`.

Pay attention! When you are using `http://localhost:port/podcast/seccion` the ***"default"*** route template is engaged and therefore the `id` is `0`.

But, if you will define the default `id` value in the action method like `public IActionResult Seccion(int id=300)` the following URL's `https://localhost:port/podcast/seccion` or `https://localhost:port/podcast/seccion/[some_number_here]` will properly work too.

For more information see [Set up conventional route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-up-conventional-route)

Comment: No, what I want is for the URL to be clean only with localhost / podcast / section / stories and thus internally pass the value 300, but without placing it in the browser.

Comment: I tried it, change the order but it keeps getting 0 in the id value. :(

Comment: @Daniel Lazarte: Pay attention, if you use the `[Route(...)]` attribute it will take high priority. If you don't use the routing attribute, it will work. What exactly an URL are you using? If you use `https://localhost:port/podcast/seccion` then you **MUST** define the default id value in the action method like `public IActionResult Seccion(int id=300)`.

Comment: That is exactly what I do not want, because I will have more routes on the endpoints. MapControllerRoute and thus be able to pass the id internally. If I put it in the controller it will always have the value 300 for all routes. 
That is, I will also have localhost / podcast / section / tech for example and internally I will pass the value 400 for example, but not in the URL

Comment: @Daniel Lazarte: You wrote "**localhost / podcast / section / tech**". What this is means? Is this URL `https://localhost:port/podcast/section/tech`?

Comment: correct, in the example I have the path localhost: xx / podcast / section / stories but I will have more sections, for example localhost: xx / podcast / section / tech and naturally this I have to configure it with another id. if you explain me? that is, I do not want to pass numbers in the URL, I want it to work with a clean URL and internally pass a code to it

Comment: @Daniel Lazarte: I made a change in the "historias" route. If you enter   `https://localhost:port/podcast/seccion/historias` URL the `Seccion()` action will be called with default `id` equal `300` and the action method is defined as `public IActionResult Seccion(int id)`, without the default value. Try this.

Comment: Excellent. This is what I was looking for. I really appreciate your support. I don't know if I put my question right, but this is what I was looking for. Thank you very much and blessings

Comment: @Daniel Lazarte: Understood. But I would suggest that you try to use the [Route()] attribute instead of conventional routing. I think it will make your code more easy to understand...

Answer (score 1):

you should set your default value in Action

```
public IActionResult Seccion(int id = 300)
{
   
    return View();
}
```

when call `https://localhost:xxx/podcast/seccion` `id` is `300`
and when call `https://localhost:xxx/podcast/seccion/1` `id` is `1`

for more information [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#:%7E:text=Routing%20is%20responsible%20for%20matching,configured%20when%20the%20app%20starts.)

Comment: No, what I want is for the URL to be clean only with localhost / podcast / section / stories and thus internally pass the value 300, but without placing it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

Your controller:-

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("[action]/{id}")
public IActionResult Seccion(int id)
{
   
    return View();
}
```

when you call `https://localhost:xxx/podcast/seccion/id` you will found your output as expected and your id is 300 by default. or you can use simply this for default id value:- `public IActionResult Seccion(int id ?? 300)`

Comment: No, what I want is for the URL to be clean only with localhost / podcast / section / stories and thus internally pass the value 300, but without placing it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a value to the ID on the url, like this:

`https://localhost:44394/podcast/seccion/300`

Result:
[image]

For more related content, please refer to the official document:

[Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Cor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)e

Comment: No, what I want is for the URL to be clean only with localhost / podcast / section / stories and thus internally pass the value 300, but without placing it in the browser.